# Pass checkboxes to controller asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have some images that every images has a checkbox beside like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select" value="<%=item.Id%>" />
```

Now I want to send the selected checkboxes to controller by clicking a hyperlink. I have :

```
<a href='<%: Url.Action("DeleteSelected", "Product", new { @ShopID = ViewBag.shopIDempty } ) %>'>Delete</a>
```

and in controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteSelected(int[] select, int ShopID)
    {

        foreach (int checkBoxSelected in select)
        {
            //Do something...               
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But nothing pass to int[] select and it is null always. What is wrong?

Comment: If you want to pass arguments to DeleteSelected by link you have to manually add selected checkbox values to link arguments in other case you should wrap checkboxes with form and POST checked items with button click

Answer (score 0):

Do these==>
1) Make an array which contains the selected checkbox value

```
var delete= new Array();

     $('.checkboxed').live('click', function () {
                if ($(this)[0].checked == true) {
                    var itemdel= $(this).val();
                    delete.push(itemdel);
                } else {
                    var remve =  $(this).val();
                    for (var i = 0; i < delete.length; i++) {
                        if (delete[i] == remve) {
                            delete.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

2)Make an ajax call on clicking the hyper link

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/Product/DeleteSelected'
+ '?ShopID =' + ShopIdValue,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $.toJSON(delete),


                success: function (result) {
                  window.location.href=result;
                },


                async: false,
                cache: false
            });
```

3) Make your Action Like this

```
public ActionResult DeleteSelected(int[] select)
{
var shopid= Request["ShopID "];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteSelected(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        string[] test = collection.GetValues("select");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I do want to note that the approach you are taking requires a form to wrap the all of the checkboxes or you need to specifically build an object to send to the controller as Syed showed. If you go the form approach, you will need to either use the a link to trigger the form submit or convert the a link to a submit button and have a hidden field for the ShopID.